# Sending data back from controller in Pylons using jQuery Form Plugin

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pylons

I'm trying to figure out how to send a variable from the controller's view back with the success callback using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form). In the example on the website, they show how to do it with PHP, which is fine, but we're using Pylons (I'm on the front-end).

Therefore, I'd like to know basically how to send a variable from the controller back to the view more specifically, this one: `admin_url = url('admin', action='brand', id=brand.id qualified=True)`.

In the success callback function, I was thinking of maybe something like: data.admin_url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by using responseText within the success callback. I chose json as the dataType.